# Which species of rotifer is this?

Tags: species-identification, microbiology

If found this in a moss sample. 
[image]
[image]

Comment: Welcome to Bio.SE! What attempts to answer this question have you already taken? We ask that all question posters here attempt to search for an answer to their own question and explicitly indicate what research they've already done, what they learned, and what is still confusing or unknown to them. Our goal is not to simply be an answer site, but rather a site that promotes self-learning with some expert help along the way :). Please take a moment to edit your post with this additional detail, and it will likely be received more positively by our community. Thanks!

Comment: Also, for [tag:species-identification] questions, please be sure to include *all* relevant information mentioned [here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tags/species-identification/info) (which you saw when typing the question). specifically, please at least add an approximation of size of your specimen and indicate where you took your sample. Thanks.